# File servers for Android?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, file-transfer, ftp

Do any good file servers exist for Android that do not require root?  Ideally, it'd be nice to just be able to have an SMB share, but the only app I was able to find for this ([Samba Filesharing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba&hl=en)) requires root.

I'm currently using FTPDroid, but it's pretty slow (I'm getting about 200 KB/s downloads on my n600 wifi).  Are there any better options?

I'm using a Verizon Galaxy S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tons of alternatives. Find a list of FTPServers in [this German thread](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/438381/) ([Google Translate version](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.de%2Fde%2Fandroid%2Fforum%2Fthread%2F438381%2F)), others like WebDAV and Samba can be found [here](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/438399/) (again: [Google Translate version](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.androidpit.de%2Fde%2Fandroid%2Fforum%2Fthread%2F438399%2F)).

I'd say you could give [FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer) a try, sounds promising. No root mentiones, highly rated.

Alternatively, you might want to try [DoMobile FTP share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.ftpshare) (very small: less than 30 kB!) or their new app [eShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.eshare). Meanwhile I even managed to locate [SwiFTP](http://ppareit.github.com/swiftp/) again (somebody continues the project, finally!), which should be fast and lightweight.

Comment: Still want to try the rest of the suggestions, but FTPServer is so far much faster than FTPDroid.

Comment: Yeah. But it's a real pity that SwiFTP seems no longer available -- small and fast and feature-rich, it seemed the best choice. But as for your requirements, when walking the list you might stick with DoMobile (small and handsome, and reported to be really fast). Make sure to let us know your choice then :)

Comment: DoMobile's new app called `eshare` turned out great.  Fast and reliable so far.  If you add that to your answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: At your service xD

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is access your device from a Computer, my favourite app is [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). Allows you to browse files file a lot more. Doesn't require root. I've found that I can get 1.5 / 2mb/s on a busy network

Comment: I do use AirDroid from time to time, and it's pretty cool.  I'd prefer to find something that I can access natively through Windows though, rather than through a browser.

Answer (score 2):

I use [SSHDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid), which doesn't require root (although if you have root, it will take advantage of it). This has the dual advantage that it can not only be used for file transfers (using SFTP), but since it's an SSH server, it also allows you to open a remote shell on your phone. I usually get ~1Mbps via WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [Servers Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate).

Comment: Would be nice to give a reason for your suggestion. Guess it's the "many different servers in one app" making you say so? Or did you try it, and can include some feedback on what you liked about it?

Comment: I tested it on an old device I owned and was really keen about it. 
Currently I'am running a lightweight DNS server on my old device.

Answer (score -2):

I created [WiFi FTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medhaapps.wififtpserver) for this purpose.

Comment: It's OK to name your own app. But it's a rule to disclose your involvement. Sure you found it good if you wrote it – otherwise you'd have to hit yourself for bad coding.

Comment: That's two questions, both with little information touting your own app. That sort of behavior is frowned on around here. If you don't want people to flag your answers as spam, I suggest you answer questions where you're _not_ suggesting your app.